# How to convert .ps to .png in a ps.map script?

Tags: grass-gis, png

I already managed to create a .ps file. How do I convert it to .png using a GRASS script?

Comment: On which operating system are you working?

Comment: Windows. I am using GRASS GIS

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows), there is a Windows version. I was referring in my previous post also to IM, although under Linux.

Comment: Will this work with GRASS gis for its ps.map script? or it is an entirely separate software just for converting images?

Comment: Separate software to convert and manipulate images.

Comment: Can its functions be called using a script or integration with GRASS?

Comment: Yes, you can integrate the "convert" tool of ImageMagick in a simple script following the ps.map or other commands to convert to PNG.

Comment: I installed ImageMagick but it displays `ERROR: convert : illegal request` after I included `convert 22.ps 23.png` in my ps.map